# Limiting scope of script arguments

Tags: powershell, scope, arguments

With a regular variable you can use the $private: specifier to limit scope, but that seems to not work with script arguments. And I have a script with a bunch of arguments that are by default global, which I took advantage of in a fit of laziness. Now I am trying to rectify the situation, and ideally I would make all those argument variables to be private. Am i missing some other approach, or are script arguments just global by their nature?

Comment: Can't really answer without seeing your script, but it sounds like an odd problem. What's wrong with having global script args? Are you repeatedly (re)using the same variable names?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your trying to solve, but have you explored using parameter sets?

Comment: I had been using the same names, and I am now addressing that issue. My thought was, if I could force the arguments to local scope it would help in nailing down my inappropriate usage. But search/replace is also an option, and probably better than inducing a crash as an editing technique. ;) As for parameter sets, I think I need to look into that for a different refinement. Right now I have two scripts that do much the same thing, but take very different arguments. Consolidating into a single file would solve some issues there.

Comment: Script arguments should be `$script:` scoped I believe, are they not or are you confusing script-global with actually-global?

Comment: That is what I originally thought too, but I am able to access these vars without any specifier from functions in loaded modules, and my understanding is that only global scope can be accessed from modules. I also had a regular var defined in the parent script, but not an argument of the script, which I had specifically set to script scope, and I couldn't access that from module functions until I changed it to global. The fact that I can access the argument vars seems to suggest they are global, or perhaps that arguments are treated differently from regular vars.

Comment: Show us an example that we can reproduce. It is just speculation now which makes the process take longer